# Newtonsoft.json not following default behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, json.net

We use Newtonsoft.json quite extensively throughout our solution, which is hosted in a few different environments, and it it's always worked just fine for us until Wednesday. We released a new version of our product and for a few hours all was well, then Newtonsoft's default behaviour changed around 5 hours after we released to our production environment and it started ignoring null and default values when serializing. This new version has been in test for about 3 months, around a month of that on this very server, and we have never experienced this.

We're using Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.2 in a .Net Framework 4.6.1 Web Forms application.

We're setting JSON values to hidden elements in the web form from the partial control's .cs file so that Vue.js can pick up the JSON and display in the UI. Whether this is or is not a good idea is beside the point. The code is as follows.

```
ExampleWebFormComponent.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);
```

It's pretty simple stuff, there are no serialization attributes in the model that is being serialized and in every other environment, even 2 other environments on the same server, this has always worked without any issue whatsoever.

I've investigated with colleagues for 2 days and we can't find any reason why the Newtonsoft.Json's default serialization behaviour would change at runtime. I was hoping someone on here might have some insight as to what could change the default behaviour, besides the obvious explicit exclusion.

There are no references to the `NullValueHandling` or `DefaultValueHandling` enums in the Newtonsoft.Json project in our solution.

The web config has the following reference to Newtonsoft.Json

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Think about what you are saying. Something that was working a certain way, and was not changed, started acting differently. That is not possible, the variables in this situation are your code and your data. Are you able to remote debug? What is your evidence for this claim? Logging? Different application behavior?

Comment: I think it's obvious that something has changed, but what didn't change is the call the JsonConvert. I know it changed because following the deployment, 4 separate people tested the functionality and it worked and there are logs of it working about 4 hours after. We don't have a wrapper around the call to JsonConvert so that's why I'm asking the question, do you know of a way to change the default behaviour outside of explicitly including it in the call?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is changing the major version of the library.

Comment: I checked DLL versions that were deployed to each environment and all are 11.0.2. I have been making my way through all the docs and so far can't see of a way to globally changing default settings.

Comment: Here is the code for for `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);` https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L528 . It's nit using any Jconverter setting or anything it's just passing a null. You can try to add the real Newtonsoft.Json to the solution under and directly step thought `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(` at debug.

Comment: And at the end of the line it's calling the `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/926d2f0f42292cfcdf07cdadeb501b73fd5b1d52/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs#L621 . But if there is reference to NullValueHandling  and NullValueHandling . I don't see how you can change the behavior without calling those setting. You can perhaps log the value of JsonConvert.DefaultSettings

Comment: Do you have any runtime declarations for Newtonsoft in your web.config?  I know for some clients we've had to specify version numbers, or a ````0 - [currentVersion]```` to signify that multiple versions might be in play.

Comment: I've edited the main description to include the web.config reference to Newtonsoft.Json